# How does my modified ordinal hierarchy relate to other ordinal hierachies?

Tags: approximation, big-numbers, transfinite-recursion

I was working on my answer for [Golf a number bigger than TREE(3)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139355/golf-a-number-bigger-than-tree3/145882#145882) and I realized I couldn't use [The Hardy Hierarchy](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hardy_hierarchy) in the way wanted to. So I defined a slightly modified version:
$$H'_0(n)=n+1$$
$$H'_\alpha(n)=H'_{\alpha[n]}(H'_{\alpha[n]}(n))$$
the goal was that this would be a balance between the simplicity (to program) of [The Hardy Hierarchy](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hardy_hierarchy) and the recursion of the [Fast-growing-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy)/[Ackermann-](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399746/the-ackermann-hierarchy-vs-the-fast-growing-hierarchy) hierarchy.

note:

- The second rule assumes $(\alpha+1)[n]=\alpha$
- This is a [Grzegorczyk hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grzegorczyk_hierarchy): the result depends on the choice of fundamental sequence, you may assume I'm using standard fundamental sequences.
- $H'_\alpha(n)>H_\alpha(n)$ because $\alpha[n]\ge 0 \Rightarrow H'_{\alpha[n]}(n)\ge n+1$

Trough some manual working out I found:

- $H'_k(n)=n+2^k$
- $H'_ω(n)>n+2^{n+1}$
- $H'_{ω+k}(n)>(2↑↑2^k)^{n+1}$
- $H'_{ω*k}(n)>2↑^k2^n$
- $H'_{ω^ω}(n)\approx n→n→...→n $ (n arrows) but that was mostly just a guess based on the trend of $H'_{ω^0}(n),H'_{ω^1}(n),H'_{ω^2}(n)$

This suggests that $H'_{ω*\alpha}(n)\approx f_\alpha(n)$
or $H'_\alpha(n)\approx f_\alpha(n)$ for $\alpha>ω^ω$

But this is mainly my (and [Simply Beautiful Art's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/272831/simply-beautiful-art)) suspicion could someone with more knowledge about ordinals please try to approximate $H'_\alpha$ better (more precisely, more rigidly,...) using an other ordinal hierarchy?

Comment: You may wish that you are using, say, the [Grzegorczyk hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grzegorczyk_hierarchy). You'll find that an ordinal hierarchy doesn't make sense until one defines a specific fundamental sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using standard fundamental sequences, I get

$$H'_\omega(n)=n+2^n>2\cdot n$$

From there we can prove with induction that

$$H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha}(n)>f_\alpha(n)\quad\forall\alpha>0$$

Base case:

$$\alpha=1\implies H'_\omega(n)=n+2^n>2\cdot n=f_1(n)$$

Successor ordinal induction step:

$$\text{assume that }H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha}(n)>f_\alpha(n)$$
\begin{align}H'_{\omega\cdot(\alpha+1)}(n)&=H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha+n}(H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha+n}(n))\\&>H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha}(H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha+n-1}(H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha+n-1}(n)))\\&>H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha}(H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha}(H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha+n-2}(H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha+n-2}(n))))\\&>\dots\tag{left up to the reader}\\&>(H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha})^n(n)\\&>f_\alpha^n(n)\\&=f_{\alpha+1}(n)\end{align}

Limit ordinal induction step:

$$\text{assume that }H'_{\omega\cdot\beta}(n)>f_\beta(n)\forall\beta<\alpha,~\alpha[n]<\alpha$$
$$H'_{\omega\cdot\alpha}(n)=H'_{\omega\cdot(\alpha[n])}(n)>f_{\alpha[n]}(n)=f_\alpha(n)$$

Where the same ordinal hierarchy is used on both sides.

I fail to find a good upper bound, but hopefully a lower bound is all you really wanted.

Comment: For $H′_ω(n)$ I got $n+2^{n+1}$ But I the proof should still be correct. Also note that $H′_{ω⋅α}(n)>H′_{ω⋅(α[n])}(n)$ with my definition $H′_{ω⋅α}(n)=H′_{ω⋅(α[n])}(H′_{ω⋅(α[n])}(n))>H′_{ω⋅(α[n])}(n)$ Having a proof of our guess is really nice, and a lower bound should suffice.

Comment: Do you know anything about the transfinite version? I think the lower bound should hold up there to.

Comment: Ah, okay @fejfo

Comment: @fejfo I'm not sure I understand. The lower bound here makes no sense with ordinals in it, and we're diagonalizing at $x$, not $\beta$ in your transfinite version.

Comment: @SimplyBeatifulArt I'm diagonalizing at x, not β because α[β] wouldn't mean anything. What I really need is an uncountable ordinal A for which A[β] would be defined but I was hoping to avoid uncountable ordinals (but I think I will need them anyway so that probably won't be the final version).

Comment: @SimplyBeatifulArt and for $f_\alpha(\beta)$ to make sense somebody should define an transfinite version of the fgh. But I have some ideas about the current version of the extended hierarchy too I will write down first.

EDIT: maybe I will edit the definition first instead of having to redo my work.

Comment: @fejfo I've already previously tackled such an idea. I'll warn you in advance that using uncountable ordinals in such a manner is fruitless in the grand scheme of things.