# Sanity check: does $D_{\omega_9}(9)$ exceed TREE(3)?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, recursion, ordinals, big-numbers

## TREE(3)

For the [Golf a number bigger than TREE(3)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139355/golf-a-number-bigger-than-tree3) challenge I wrote a program but I'm not sure it is bigger than TREE(3).

> The function TREE(k) gives the length of the longest sequence of trees T1, T2, ... where each vertex is labelled with one of k colours, the tree Ti has at most i vertices, and no tree is a minor of any tree following it in the sequence.
>
> TREE(1) = 1, with e.g. T1 = (1).
>
> TREE(2) = 3: e.g. T1 = (1); T2 = (2)--(2); T3 = (2).

Because of my limited knowledge of TREE(k) and ordinals I decided to post a question here first before submitting my answer.

You can view the code and a limited explanation [here](https://repl.it/NH4p/14) but I will define and  explain the D function here.

## Notation

My program is highly recursive, it produces functions to put inside other functions.

- $\omega_0=0$,  $\omega_1=\omega$,  $\omega_1=\Omega$,...
- $\alpha_n$ means $cf(\alpha)=\omega_n$
  so $\alpha_0$ means $\alpha$ is a natural number
- I will represent ordinals as functions (in lambda calculus) which their fundamental sequence (e.g. $\omega_1\cdot 2=\lambda x_0. \omega_1+x_0$) and call these functions using square brackets e.g. $(\omega_1\cdot 2)[5]=\omega+5$

## Definition

1. $\omega_n=\lambda \alpha_k. \alpha_k$ with $k<n$
2. $\alpha_n+1=\lambda \beta_n. \alpha_n$
3. $D_\alpha(\beta)=H'_\alpha(H'_\alpha(\beta))=H'^{2}_\alpha(\beta)$
4. $H'_0(\alpha_n)=\alpha_n+1$
5. $H'_{\alpha_{n+1}}(\beta_k)=D_{H'_{\alpha_{n+1}}(\omega_n)}(\beta_k)$ if $k<n$
6. $H'_{\alpha_{n+1}}(\beta_n)=D_{\alpha_{n+1}[\beta_n]}(\beta_n)$
7. $H'_{\alpha_0+1}(\beta_n)=D_{\alpha_0}(\beta_n)$
8. $H'_{\alpha_{k+1}}(\beta_n)=\lambda \gamma_k. D_{\alpha_{k+1}[\gamma_k]}(\beta_n)$ if $0\le k<n$

My number is $D_{\omega_9}(9)$ but I can easily change it to $D_{\omega_{10^9}}(9)$ if required.

## In words

1. $\omega_n$ is the identity function for ordinals of smaller cofanity.
2. The successor of $\alpha$ is the function that returns $\alpha$ for all input (this is to avoid having to handle successor and limit ordinals separately )
3. $D$ is the doubling function it iterates $H'$ once. This is a balance between the [hardy hierarchy](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hardy_hierarchy), which doesn't iterate at all, and the [fast-growing hierarchy](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy), which iterates n times.
4. $H'_0$ is the successor function, both for functions and numbers

**$H'_\alpha(\beta)$**:

5. if the domain of $\alpha$ is **so large** a size smaller could still fit $\beta$, use $H'$ on $\alpha$ until the domain is just large enough.
   (this is a way to avoid having multiple calls to H' in my code
   e.g. $\alpha_1=H'_{\omega_2}(\omega_1)$ and $H'_{\alpha_1}(9)$
6. if the domain of $\alpha$ is **just large enough** use $\alpha[\beta]$

if the domain of $\alpha$ is **too small**:

7. if $\alpha$ is an **integer** use it's predecessor.
8. **else** define the result to be **the function** that uses $\alpha[\gamma]$ as
   the new subscript when $\gamma$ is put in. The result has the same
   domain as $\alpha$

**note**:

- $H'_{\alpha_n}(\beta_m) \in T_m \text{ if } m\le n \text{ or } n=0$
- $H'_{\alpha_n}(\beta_m) \in T_n \text{ if } n<m$

## The ordinal interpretation

You don't have to read this is you don't want. The question is if $D_{\omega_9}(9)>TREE(3)$.
But I want to give some more explanation for **why** I believe my number is bigger than TREE(3).

The functions in program have strong similarities with ordinals
This is the definition for the set of tree-ordinals with order type $n$:
$$\alpha\in T_n \Leftrightarrow
 \begin{cases}
\alpha=0\\
\alpha=\beta+1 \text{ and } \beta\in T_n\\
\alpha:T_k\mapsto T_n \text{ with } k<n\\
\end{cases}$$

### Note

- $T_k \subset T_n \text{ if } k<n$ but except for this it perfectly aligns with the explanation I gave earlier.
- $T_0$ is still the set of natural numbers, since the 3rd rule, which generates all the limit ordinals, can't be used yet.
- My definition of $\omega_n$ is different than usual, usually $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal ($\Omega$) but for me that's $\omega_2$ I did this to keep $\alpha_n \in T_n$

### Notation interpreted as ordinals

- $\alpha_{k}$ is an ordinal with  order type k ( $k=\min(n:\alpha\in T_n)$ )
- $\alpha_n[\beta_k]$ is the $\beta$th element of $\alpha$'s fundamental sequence. This is defined when $k<n$.

## The ordinal idea behind my number

I believe $\omega_9$ acts as on ordinal about the size of $\tau[9]$ in $H'$.
Since $H'_{\omega*\alpha}(n)>f_\alpha(n)$, My number $D_{\omega_9}(9)=H'^{2}_{\omega_9}(9)\approx H'^{2}_{\tau[9]}(9)>f_{\tau[9]}(9)>f_{ϑ(Ω^ω ω)+1}(9)>TREE(9)$

$H'$ is a modified version of the [Hardy Hierarchy](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hardy_hierarchy). The idea behind $H'$ is that $H'_{\alpha+1}$ = $H'^{2}_{\alpha}$ $\Rightarrow$ $H'_{\alpha_n+\omega_n} \text{ iterates } H'_{\alpha_n}$ $\Rightarrow$ $H'_{\omega*\alpha}(n)>f_\alpha(n)$. You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489780/how-does-my-modified-ordinal-hierarchy-relate-to-other-ordinal-hierachies).

Than the idea of an ordinal hierarchy was expended from a using a countable ordinal to generate huge integers, to use huge $\alpha_{n+1}$ to generate huge $\beta_n$.

The 5th definition was than added to iterate $H'$ on the ordinal slot. If I did this correctly this should mean that $H'_{\omega_{n+k}}(n)>f_\tau(n)$ for some reasonably small k.

## Examples

These early expansions created a lot of insight into my function for me, so I'll post them here too.

### Some very early expansions

The 5th definition makes $D_{\omega_9}(9)$ expand to $H'_{\omega_9}(H'_{\alpha_8}(H'_{\alpha_7}(H'_{\alpha_6}(H'_{\alpha_5}(H'_{\alpha_4}(H'_{\alpha_3}(H'_{\alpha_2}(D_{\alpha_1}(9)))))))))$
$= H'_{\omega_9}(H'_{\alpha_8}(H'_{\alpha_7}(H'_{\alpha_6}(H'_{\alpha_5}(H'_{\alpha_4}(H'_{\alpha_3}(H'_{\alpha_2}(H_{\alpha_1}(D_{\alpha_1[9]}(9))))))))))$

$$\alpha_8=H'_{\omega_9}(\omega_8)=D_{\omega_8}(\omega_8)=H'_{\omega_8}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8))$$
\begin{align}
\ \alpha_7 & = H'_{\alpha_8}(\omega_7) \\
& = D_{\alpha_8[\omega_7]}(\omega_7) \\
& = D_{H'_{\omega_8}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8))[\omega_7]}(\omega_7) \\
& = D_{D_{\omega_8[\omega_7]}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8))}(\omega_7) \\
& = D_{D_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8))}(\omega_7) \\
& = H'_{H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8)))}(H'_{H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8)))}(\omega_7))\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ \alpha_6 & =H'_{\alpha_7}(\omega_6) \\
\ & = D_{\alpha_7[\omega_6]}(\omega_6) \\
\ & = D_{H'_{H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8)))}(H'_{H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_7}(H'_{\omega_8}(\omega_8)))}(\omega_7))[\omega_6]}(\omega_6) \\
\ & = \ ...
\end{align}
$$\alpha_5=H'_{\alpha_6}(\omega_5)$$
$$\alpha_4=H'_{\alpha_5}(\omega_4)$$
$$\alpha_3=H'_{\alpha_4}(\omega_3)$$
$$\alpha_2=H'_{\alpha_3}(\omega_2)$$
$$\alpha_1=H'_{\alpha_2}(\omega_1)$$

If you want too truly experience the madness I recommend trying to work out $\alpha_1[3]$ but I didn't get very far.

### Some very approximate expansions

\begin{align}
D_{\omega_9}(9) & = H'^{2}_{\omega_9}(9)  \\
 & > H'_{\omega_9}(9) \\ 
 & = D_{H'_{\omega_9}(\omega_8)}(9) \\
 & > D_{\omega_{8}*2}(9) \\ 
 & > H'_{\omega_{8}*2}(9) \\
 & > H'_{\omega_{7}^2}(9)\\
 & > H'_{2 ↑^{\omega_{6}} \omega_{6}}(9)\\
 & >  ...
\end{align}

### Conclusion

I couldn't get past $\omega_6$ and I ignored all the iteration of D so once $H'_{\alpha_1}(9)$ is finally reached the computer will have to work back up trough all of those extra iterations too.

But that wouldn't even be necessary because $f_{ϑ(Ω^ω ω)}(9)>TREE(3)$ so if $\alpha_1>ϑ(Ω^ω ω)$ my number should be big enough.

So is $\alpha_1>ϑ(Ω^ω ω)$?
I think it should be, but it's quite possible I made a mistake somewhere. Did I?

Comment: I am not sure whether an upper bound for $TREE(3)$ is known. "$TREE(4)$" as entry will of course not be allowed. I do not quite get what your number is. Are you just iterating through the hierachy's ?

Comment: @Peter I got the TREE(n) approximation from [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/TREE_sequence) I've just noticed it's a lower bound but other people used it too in their answers so I think it's fine (and my number should be much larger). What I'm trying to do is something like:
$a1=\omega_9$  
$a2=H'_{a1}(\omega_8)$  
$a3=H'_{a2}(\omega_7)$  
$a4=H'_{a3}(\omega_6)$  
$a5=H'_{a4}(\omega_5)$  
$a6=H'_{a5}(\omega_4)$  
$a7=H'_{a6}(\omega_3)$  
$a8=H'_{a7}(\omega_2)$  
$a9=H'_{a8}(\omega_1)$  
my number$>H'_{a9}(9)$

Comment: What is $\omega_9$ ? Dont't we need an argument, say $\omega_9(9)$ ?

Comment: @Peter what I mean with $\omega_n[\alpha_k]=\alpha_k$ with $k<n$ is $\alpha_k$ is the $\alpha_k$-th element of $\omega_n$'s fundamental sequence. But I forgot to mention I used tree-ordinals in my code, which means instead of saying $\alpha=sup(\alpha[0],\alpha[1],\alpha[2],...)$ you simply say $\alpha$ is the fundamental sequence, $\omega_n$ is the function that takes $\alpha_k$ and returns $\alpha_k$. In my code this can be seen as `w=lambda n:((lambda x:x),n)` (I use a pair to store the fundamental sequence and the cardinality, the checks for what `x` is happen when `w(n)(x)` is called)

Comment: @Peter Just an FYI, the challenge here says that instead of aiming to beat TREE(3) which doesn't have any solid upper bounds, we may aim to beat the fgh approximation $f_{\vartheta(\Omega^\omega\cdot\omega)}(3)$.

Comment: Oops. It should be $f_{\vartheta(\Omega^\omega\cdot\omega)+1}(3)$ @Peter

Comment: @Peter I completely rewrote the question, I explain it with recursive functions now, could you please take an other look at it?

Comment: @fejfo I am very interested in huge numbers, but honestly, I have no experience with the ordinals coming into play here. I do not think that I can decide whether the number you constructed passes $TREE(3)$. If I remember right, Wythagoras and Deedlit are experts on this subject. Maybe they can shed light on this stuff.

Comment: @Peter and fejfo, you may be interested in joining my [Discord server](https://discord.gg/AmRtUw), meant for studying really large ordinals. And it may interest you that I recently wrote a program that possibly outputs a number as large as $f_{\psi(\Omega_{M+ \Omega_{M+ \Omega_{\ddots}}})}(999)$, where $M$ is the first Mahlo 'ordinal'. [Here](https://tio.run/##NYxNDsIgEIX3nqLdNGoGU5agIwchs6BAQ4MSqzXGtJ69UlNX78v7uz@b9zy3yM4GEjRooMc0WnDg0RxLW6heGsSshnHpEetp8lXlMigrfaG0Xsqt9ssceqLMbmWwJNOJKyFLl5utbiAx/rPtcpCkHjDbFhKBo7xyq52VceXl/2sgos9mGzCiEGJ3GLqrf4wBtWYcOIQlDdjqAHGPkV6hu/gilFhvbkWc5y8).

Comment: @fejfo Forget $TREE(3)$, try to beat this number : http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Little_Bigeddon

Comment: @Peter I'll take a look at that, I know `TREE(3)` isn't the largest number but I still wonder about how big my number is.

Edit: Little Bigeddon is uncomputalbe it can't realistically be beaten with a program